# Split a file line by line in to multiple arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Below is the file, entries are tab separated

sample.txt

```
id\a_po87y Jack leader
id\ruio66 John_Marsha leader
id\rzd766 123_Smart_option fresher
.......
........
etc
```

I'm trying to split the values in 3 arrays like below

```
id = ["id\a_po87y", "id\ruio66", "id\rzd766", ....]

store = ["Jack", "John_Marsha", "123_Smart_option", ....]

group = ["leader", "leader", "fresher", ....]
```

My incomplete code below.

```
id = Array.new
store = Array.new
group = Array.new
File.open("D:\sample.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
    id << line.split("\t")
    #not sure how to cpature the remaining entries
end
```

I'm very new to ruby and I have searched other options in Ruby documentation unfortunately I cant find what I need.Any help please

"Output should be" in 3 different arrays and not in a single array

```
id = ["id\a_po87y", "id\ruio66", "id\rzd766", ....]

store = ["Jack", "John_Marsha", "123_Smart_option", ....]

group = ["leader", "leader", "fresher", ....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`transpose` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) seems what you're looking for. Try this one.

```
file = File.open("D:\sample.txt", "r")
file.each_line.map { |line| line.split("\t") }.transpose.each do |fields|
  puts fields
end
```

Comment: Fantastic. I didn't expect the transpose method.Thank you.
I tried using - `fields.first` to extract the only the ids and assign to an array called id, but I cant separte the fields.I'm trying like below

`id = ["id\a_po87y", "id\ruio66", "id\rzd766", ....]

store = ["Jack", "John_Marsha", "123_Smart_option", ....]

group = ["leader", "leader", "fresher", ....]`

Comment: Sorry man I don't get it. Can you open another question and put the code?

Comment: Sorry I cant post another question within 90 minutes. I have edited the question and asked my query under the section "Output should be" . Thanks again

Comment: I tried something like
`file = File.open('./file');
fields = file.each_line.map { |line| line.split("\t") };
id, store = fields` and it works for me. Let me know

Comment: its giving output as 

**puts id** 

`id\a_po87y
Jack
leader`

puts store

`id\ruio66
John_Marsha
leader`

but I'm looking for 

**puts id**

`id\a_po87y
id\ruio66
id\rzd766`

and puts store,  should be 

`Jack
John_Marsha
123_Smart_option`

I suppose we have to split the obtained array further in to 3 arrays.

Comment: Oh sure, I forgot transpose :D